# Behaviour of createEntityManagerFactory() with existing JTA Transaction

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

In a jar I've written there is a call to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()` which worked fine using a Glassfish/EclipseLink configuration. However, if i deploy the same code to an JBoss application server using Hibernate as persistence provider, I get the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction!
```

In fact the jar is called from within an open transaction, and I wonder if I offend against some existing standard in doing so.

Btw. someone else has filed a bug report [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6651?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel).